# Connect to Athena without access?

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, pyathena

I need to connect to Athena using Python.

The code used is as follows:

```
import pyathena
import pandas as pd

athena_conn = pyathena.connect(access_key, 
                 secret_key,
                 s3_staging_dir,
                 region_name)

df = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM db.tableLIMIT 10", athena_conn)
df.head(5)
```

I, personally don't have access to Athena with my AWS, hence I'm borrowing the `access_key` and `secret_access_key`

from my colleague, who has access to Athena.

I get the following error while running the code :

```
An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the StartQueryExecution operation: 

User: arn:aws:iam::xxxxx:user/xxxx is not authorized to perform: athena:StartQueryExecution on resource:
arn:aws:athena:us-east-1:xxxx:workgroup/primary because no identity-based policy allows the 
athena:StartQueryExecution action
unable to rollback
```

Is it because my account doesn't have access to Athena?

Comment: Borrowing from your colleague?  Sounds like a very bad idea.  Why don't you get your own?

Answer (score 0):

From [pyathena · PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/pyathena/#basic-usage) documentation:

```py
from pyathena import connect

cursor = connect(aws_access_key_id="YOUR_ACCESS_KEY_ID",
                 aws_secret_access_key="YOUR_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY",
                 s3_staging_dir="s3://YOUR_S3_BUCKET/path/to/",
                 region_name="us-west-2").cursor()
```

Note that each parameter is specified with a name `aws_access_key_id="YOUR_ACCESS_KEY_ID"`, rather than merely being positional. It might be that you need to specify the name of each parameter when passing them to the function.

Also, make sure the provided credentials are associated with an IAM User that has **permission to use Amazon Athena *AND* has permission to access the underlying data in Amazon S3**.

Comment: I get the following error when I provide the parameter names - `botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidSignatureException) when calling the StartQueryExecution operation: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.`

Comment: You can test your access key and secret key by using the AWS CLI `aws configure` command, which will store them in a credentials file. You can then test them with a command like `aws s3 ls s3://BUCKET-NAME`. The benefit of storing credentials this way is that your Python program will automatically use, so you don't need to include them in your source code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the user in the error message you redacted is your colleagues user then he doesn't have the required permissions. At least not for the workgroup you are using.

It's hard to say what the exact permissions your collegue has without posting the policy document attached to his user.

However, the error message is quite clear that he is lacking the permission: `athena:StartQueryExecution`. This permission must be given in an [Identity Based Policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies.html#policies_id-based) to his user.

Note that the permission must also be given for the resource in question (or for * for all resources).

An example of a valid policy document for this permission would be:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "athena:StartQueryExecution",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:athena:*:12345:workgroup/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

This policy allows StartQueryExecution on all workgroups in account `12345`. It's possible he is lacking this permission entirely or has it for a specific workgroup.

If he has the permission for a specific workgroup you should configure your client to run the query in that workgroup. Currently you are trying to run it on the default `primary` workgroup.